# MySQL SELECT COUNT() up to 1000 times slower than SELECT in FULLTEXT/MATCH searches

Tags: mysql, count, full-text-search, mariadb

Context: this is MySQL database for a B2C project.

I am using a SELECT COUNT() sentence to know in advance the number of rows a regular SELECT will return. This is just for pagination calculations in the GUI. The problem I am having is, simply in my laptop local setup, SELECT COUNT() query duration is in the dangerous order of 1s vs SELECT query, which is in the order of 1ms. Around 1000 times slower!!

I have isolated the problem and created a separate project for the purpose of having a simple test bed. A table *document* was created this way:

```
drop table document;
create table document (
  id       int primary key auto_increment,
  brand    varchar(128) not null,
  ref      varchar(32) not null,
  title    varchar(128) not null,
  brief    varchar(256) not null,
  content  mediumtext not null,
  fulltext key (brand, ref, title, brief, content)
);
```

To make a model of the real problem I populated the table with 2000 random text rows, having *brand* and *ref* 1 word, *title* 6 words, *brief* 12 words and *content* around 50kbyte in words.

The typical user query is something like:

```
select id, brand, ref, title, brief, content from document
where match (brand, ref, title, brief, content) against ('espadas' in boolean mode)
limit 24
```

so the COUNT() query should be:

```
select count(id)
from document 
where match (brand, ref, title, brief, content) against ('espadas' in boolean mode)
```

Using a local setup in my laptop the empirical duration of regular queries is between 1-3ms, good enough for me. I was prepared for even longer durations, having in mind the value of a FULLTEXT/MATCH search for the user. Count() queries rise up to 1s, a huge time that leads to a higher risk, even at low concurrencies.

Any idea of how to reduce this long SELECT COUNT() duration?

MySQL version is: 10.1.10-MariaDB and document table is InnoDB.

Comment: Are there more than 24 results? The first query can stop after that. The count  query has to continue, That's why it's slower. (Sry don't have a solution.)

Comment: Good point Roland Starke, I forgot to comment the number of rows counted for the word 'espadas" is 555 over a total number of rows of 2000. So no big deal to spend 1s.

Comment: I Just checked on my system, the count takes 0,000 sec and the 24 rows take 0,015 sec. As content i copied half of your question here.

Comment: Could you detail MySQL version?

Comment: If the count is taking orders of magnitude longer to perform, why not run the `SELECT` query, and then count the results you are returned using whatever language you're using to process the data into the GUI, instead of running a pre-fetch query and then a fetch query?

Comment: Maybe this could be an idea, even for 2000 rows John, but with loads of 50kbyte in content column I gues is not a good solution. 50k x 2k = 100Mbyte in the worst case and 50 Mybte in the average.

Comment: Context is important here: you can choose a brute-force solution for a local application but for a B2C architecture every extra ms has to be multiplied by the number of concurrent users to avoid spoiling the service latency. Roland Starke showed some results that behave the way it was expected by me. Maybe this is an issue of my current version that has been fixed in later MySQL versions?

Comment: OK guys. As I supposed by the results of Roland Starke, this was a version issue. In spite of I used the term 'MySQL' in the title and tags I was using MariaDB 10.1.10, as I recognize in the last line of my question. I just installed MySQL 8 and results are as expected: ~2.4ms for select and ~1.3ms for select count. Thanks for the ideas and suggestions.

Comment: Some of the inconsistencies are due to the Query cache.  Rerun your timing tests thus:  `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`.  Note:  MySQL 8 has gotten rid of the Query cache.

Comment: Thank you @rick-james. This is a good explanation of why it worked perfectly in MySQL 8!